# How to disable 'try it' button in loopBack explorer?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I want to use the loopBack explorer as read-only for the viewer

Figured out the element displaying the try it but doesn't know where to disable it.

Comment: disabling in client or server side? or both?

Comment: on Server side @ShaharShokrani

Comment: Which loopback version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

From the LoopBack 3.x documentation:

> When you create your app with the LoopBack application generator,
>   access control is automatically enabled, except if you choose the
>   “empty-server” application type. To enable access control for an
>   “empty-server” application, you must add a boot script that calls
>   enableAuth(). For example, in server/boot/authentication.js:
>
> ```
> module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {  
>     server.enableAuth(); 
> };
> ```

Read more about controlling data access [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Controlling-data-access.html).